# Is it possible to change an adapter property based on which listview uses it?

Tags: android, listview, adapter, listview-adapter

I have the following `Fragment` A, which contains 3 tabs (fragments): tab 1,2,3. Each tab has its own `listView`. Tab 2 and 3 use the same `listViewAdapter` with only one difference where in tab 2 I need to show one extra `Layout`, which I don't need in tab 3. The `listViewAdapter` is where I set all the views and logic and it is all the same in both tabs (I get some data from a request). I feel like making the same `listViewAdapter` just so I can show one extra `Layout` is redundant. Is it possible to tell the adapter to hide said `Layout` depending on the selected tab?

Comment: Do you mean that you want tab 2 to have a `ListView` and a `Layout` below it as a `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Pass the index of tab selected in adapter and distinguish your layout based on that index

Comment: I wouldn't base it on tab index.  That ties your logic to much to your UI implementation.  Instead I'd add a function like showFooView(boolean show) and call that each time a tab is loaded with the correct parameter.  And the easiest way to implement it is to probably always add that view, but set its visibility to GONE if you don't want it shown.

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafiz I meant the `listViewItem` `Layout`

Comment: @GabeSechan This is what I was looking for, but couldn't think of last night. Thank you!